# Refactor foreach statement to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, email

I have been working on a project and I'm actually refactoring some code. I have encountered myself with lots of foreach and if statements, which could be easily replace with LINQ.

But I have this code snippet, that I wonder how I could make it more functional style.

```
foreach (var notification in notifications)
{
    if (_emailService.SendEmail(notification.Message.Subject, notification.Message.Body, notification.Message.MailTo))
    {
        successNotificationIDs.AddRange(notification.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        errorCount++;
    }
}
```

The `SendEmail` method of the `EmailService` returns a bool. If its execution has been successfully, it will add an `IEnumerable` of Int to a declared collection (`successNotificationsIDs`). If not, I will increase the `errorCount` variable.

Comment: What type `notifications` have? What type notification ID have?

Comment: They are a custom type.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe notifications is a `List<T>`? Maybe ID is something like integer?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Notifications is a IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: refactoring code is only useful when you are trying to speed something up, or you gotta deal with duplicate code because some devs copy and paster crap all over the place. What you are doing, is poking poop with a barge pole. There is nothing wrong with the code, changing it LINQ wont speed it up. If you really wanted to make better code and be smarter (instead of just look smarter) you would create an interface for emails and create a better object oriented application. Not just stirring code up for no reason. -1

Comment: Since `SendEmail` is executed for a side-effect, it's inherently non functional and you should not use call it from LINQ.

Answer (score 12):

LINQ isn't a silver bullet. It stands for Language-INtegrated-**Query**, which allows **querying** objects.

Querying objects isn't something that's supposed to have side-effects. However this is precisely what you loop's body is doing.

Therefore, refactoring it to use LINQ, if at all possible, would make it much less readable than the `foreach` loop you have here.

You could always create a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object for each `notification`, and then run that.

---

Now the loop body you have, is using `AddRange` to add what appears to be a single value. Unless `notification.ID` is an `IEnumerable<whatever>`, you should be using the `Add` method to add a single value to your `successNotificationIDs`.

Comment: ID is an IEnumerable<int> actually. I don't have access to the class, but it has already been informed to change its name.

Comment: I sure hope so - it's a very misleading name to have!

Comment: @sweeden I'll update this answer with an example when I have a minute.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: It's not really that wrong to use LINQ in this instance. There are lots of useful times where a 'query' doesn't directly get or set a property. Even in the setter of some properties, sometimes there are event bindings that could be considered side effects. I think it is a personal preference of coding style, which is beneficial when a query can be easily stacked with other LINQ queries to reduce directly writing multiple `foreach` loops.

Comment: Why do you mention `Task`? How will that help here?

Comment: @svick a `Task` would decouple the execution of `SendMail()` from the loop's body, allowing for asynchronous execution. They would be created using a LINQ `Select()` method call, which would merely *project* the `notifications` into an `IEnumerable<Task>`, which also decouples the evaluation of whether a task succeeded or failed. I think the loop has too many responsibilities/side-effects to be turned into anything remotely *functional* (as mentioned in [this comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42977/refactor-foreach-statement-to-linq/42979#comment74286_42977)).

Answer (score 4):

From Stackoverflow directly, this was posted as an answer.

```
var lookup =  notifications.ToLookup(notification =>
    _emailService.SendEmail(notification.Message.Subject, 
        notification.Message.Body,
        notification.Message.MailTo));

var successfulIDs = lookup[true].SelectMany(notification => notification.ID);
var errorCount = lookup[false].Count();
```

Interesting as I didn't know the ToLookup method :).

Comment: This is a rather interesting approach, however I would seriously consider hitting an SMTP server as an async operation, especially with this kind of construct.

Comment: I will look into your answer. Thanks for the help :)!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `Where` and `Select` if you're just trying to get a list of successful IDs?

ie.

```
var successfulIDs = notifications.Where(n => _emailService.SendEmail(n.Message.Subject, 
                                                                     n.Message.Body,
                                                                     n.Message.MailTo)).
                                  Select(n => n.ID);
```

If the type of `notifications` isn't right then you should be able to use `Cast` to do that.

To check how many failed, if you're able to use `Count`:

```
long errorCount = notifications.Count() - successfulIDs.Count();
```

I don't know what your types are, but you may be able to use `Length` instead of `Count` if not. Otherwise `Cast` and then `Count`.

Additionally, here's the equivalent `foreach` in case you decide to stay with that.

```
foreach(var notification in notifications)
    if(_emailService.SendEmail(notification.Message.Subject,
                               notification.Message.Body,
                               notification.Message.MailTo))
        successNotificationIDs.AddRange(notification.ID);
```

...for which you should still be able to use the `errorCount` described above. Note that you can combine these into a single line (potentially sacrificing readability in this case).

Comment: What about the `errorCount++` line?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to go with that approach, but I need to inform the amount of notifications that failed to mailed. That's why I need the errorCount variable.

Comment: @Sweeden: Why do you need a separate variable to increase that count? You can likely just compare the `Count` of both. I've edited my answer.